# C# webform dynamic bundle scripts and css

Tags: c#, optimization, bundle

I got a big project that some scripts are bundled and some added to the page itself ( I need to use them  just in specific places).

Can I bundle my scripts  dynamically (either by page or  bundle by page content type?)

Can I use the  c# system.web.optimizing bundle ?
is There another third party .dll or script that I can use?

Cheers
Rubi